# Merge several tables together

Tags: html

I'm trying to merge tables together by using colspan, but cant seem to create my table. How can i merge tables columns together like following:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general layout would be:

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
table {
  width: 50%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

HTML code is here:

```
<table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS code is here :

```
table,td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

JS fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarpg/543c3896/

if you need exact widths for td's you have to use class selector and adjust accordingly